# how to do a post using restkit

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, post, restkit

I am building an app using restkit to talk to my webservice. First of all I'm very new to this. What I need to do is post a username and password to my webservice so that the url looks like this.

```
http://urllinkcompany.com/en/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?email=test@test.be&pwd=testtest
```

When I post this I get a json back. This json contains an status code. `status = 200 --> OK
Status = 404 --> NOT ok`

Now I tried to post something and NSLog this status code.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"data.user.cu_email":     @"cu_email",

     }];


    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];

    NSString *baseUrl = @"http://urllinkcompany.com/en/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?";
    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@email=%@&pwd=%@",baseUrl,_txtLogin.text,_txtPass.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSLog(@"url is: %@",strUrl);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
         NSLog(@"data result is %@", [result valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]);
    } failure:nil];

}
```

But I am getting this error.

```
 E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:285 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1ed57c50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x20161e70 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
2013-01-07 11:48:51.407 Offitel2[22086:907] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:152 GET '(null)'
2013-01-07 11:48:51.408 Offitel2[22086:907] E restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:173 GET '(null)' (0) [0.0010 s]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1ed57c50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x20161e70 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Kind regards

Comment: I edited my answer using RKObjectManager. does it help?

Comment: Not exactly but it helped me finding the correct answer ! so Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Here's a version without RKClient

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urllinkcompany.com/"]];

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"data.user.cu_email":     @"cu_email",
 }];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text, @"email", _txtPass.text, @"pwd", nil];

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"en/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678" delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = mapping;
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.params = params;
}];
```

And implement those two RKObjectLoaderDelegate methods:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: RKCLient does not exist in the new version, also I got errors on the delegate methods